# How to check if dirty checking is use?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have some complex screen in my Aurelia app and I would like to check easily if some bindings are **dirty checked**. I can add *console.log* in all my property getter and check when it is called but it's not easy.

Ideally I would like to get in the console the observer strategy used by each binding, but I didn't find where to plug to add this log.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can override `DirtyCheckProperty`'s subscribe method to add logging:

```js
import {DirtyCheckProperty} from 'aurelia-binding';
import * as LogManager from 'aurelia-logging';

const logger = LogManager.getLogger('my-app');

DirtyCheckProperty.prototype.standardSubscribe = DirtyCheckProperty.prototype.subscribe;
DirtyCheckProperty.prototype.subscribe = function(context, callable) {
  this.standardSubscribe(context, callable);

  logger.warn(`'${this.obj.constructor.name}.${this.propertyName}' is being dirty checked`, this.obj);
}
```

The messages would look like this in the console:

[image: console]

Here's a running example app:

https://gist.run/?id=2c863d48a2a711b8c5f93df2bb7c4a3b